# Angular : Open same app on separate tabs/windows, http requests are shared between tabs/windows when they shouldn't

Tags: angular, https

I'm currently developping an Angular 7 application with cookie-based authentication (and **have no control over the back-end**).

I need to be able to connect to different accounts at the same time, each one having its own set of values stored in a service.

By opening two tabs/windows of the same browser, I'm able to log in with two accounts, but the second account's values are leaking in the first account.

Say that on loggin in, I receive from the server

```
Time | First account (tab1)              | Second account (tab2)
t0   | (log in)                          |
t1   | `{key: 'Hello', value: 'world'}`  |
t2   | `{key: 'Hello', value: 'world'}`  | (log in)
t2   | `{key: 'Hello', value: 'you'}`    | `{key: 'Hello', value: 'you'}`
```

*(Note that all my requests are sent with the `withCredentials: true` option)*

What I'd want is the first account's requests to be separated from the second account's requests.

Now, given the cookie-based authentication and the way Angular deals with cookies, I'm guessing that it just overwrites the auth cookie on the second account's authentication.

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, the cookie is set for a domain, not a tab or window. I don't see anything Angular-specific.

Comment: You're right, I didn't even think about that... Heck...

Comment: If you need this to test something - use different browsers, e.g. Chrome and IE.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this is not a testing thing. I need my users to be able to use multiple accounts at the same time on the same browser.